# Youtube Data Api v3 login with credentials

Tags: c#, .net, api, oauth, youtube

I want to create a small application for a youtube channel with 5 people who want to upload. The channel owner asked me if there´s any way how we can let everybody upload videos without having access to any Google login details.

This is why I tried to make an application with the youtube data api v3.

I'm almost finished without any problems but **how can I avoid using "oAuth 2". I simply want to enter the login details (name, password) inside my code**.

I already tried to figure any way out, but I just can´t find any other way than using oAuth

Please don´t discuss about using oAuth, I just don´t want to use it. My coding experience is... Well, I´m pretty new in C# but I have already some experiences in Java and LUA.

Comment: Have you found solution?