# Youtube data api auto login

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

On my private video channel I want to create an application so my user can view videos. After searching, I found an authorization is needed using OAuth; the users need to login to view the video.

Is there a way to do auto login/authorization that opens a channel directly (for video upload and view)?

If someone can give hint to by pass oauth or use existing token, please comment. The same unanswered question is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945004/youtube-data-api-v3-login-with-credentials).

Answer (score 0):

You have sample codes here:

[YT Api Github](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/dotnet/PlaylistUpdates.cs)

When i doing my app with YouTube Api, i only used samples above.

About OAuth, you have some instructions here

[OAuth](https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows)

EDIT: For JS, there is a lot examples in github:

[JS API Github](https://github.com/mulesoft/js-client-oauth2)